# How to decode a CSR File?

Tags: .net, digital-certificate, csr

I ran accross a CSR file (Certificate Signing Request) and I need to extract some information from it.

There's a way to decode it using .NET Framework?

Comment: There's an online tool at http://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html if you just want to look at it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decoding a CSR is easy if you employ the [OpenSSL.NET](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net) library:

```
// Load the CSR file
var csr = new X509Request(BIO.File("C:/temp/test.csr", "r"));
OR
var csr = new X509Request(@"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----...");

// Read CSR file properties
Console.WriteLine(csr.PublicKey.GetRSA().PublicKeyAsPEM);
Console.WriteLine(csr.Subject.SerialNumber);
Console.WriteLine(csr.Subject.Organization);
.
.
.
```

X509Request type has properties to get everything out of your CSR file text.

Answer (score 56):

It's not .NET, but for interactive use, try the OpenSSL utilities. Specifically:

```
openssl req -text -in request.csr
```

Answer (score 17):

```
certutil -dump file.csr
```

Will also dump all relevant information.  Builtin in Windows by default.

Comment: For the Windows environment, I believe this answer is best because it doesn't require installing OpenSSL or utilizing any external libraries.  I spent quite a while searching for a native windows means of viewing the CSR contents, and here it is!

Comment: certutil is not builtin command in windows

Answer (score -1):

Try [Liping Dai's website](http://lipingshare.com/Asn1Editor/). His LCLib has ASN1 Parser which wrote in C#. It can decode CSR. Work for me.

Comment: The website is gone now, some of it can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20110817184958/http://lipingshare.com/Asn1Editor/.
For ASN1 parsing, you could use `openssl asn1parse -in my.csr`